# Print triangle shape with star symbol

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I wonder how do I show my kids how to print a triangle shape with basic symbol.

I started with this code

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  const strs = []
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    strs.push('*')
  }
  console.log(strs.join(''))
}
```

But I want to get

```
  *
 **
 ***
****
*****
```

or worst case skip the non-formatting row,

```
  *

 ***
  
*****
```

Comment: You'll need `Math.floor((5-i)/2)` spaces before the stars. If you want to skip even-numbered rows, use `i += 2` instead of `i++`;

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can achieve your goal

```
var spaces = "  ";
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 1) spaces = spaces.substring(0, spaces.length - 1);
  const strs = []
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    strs.push('*')
  }
  console.log(spaces + strs.join(''))
}
```

[image]

Even better if you ask me:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var strs = []
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    strs.push('*')
  }
  j = 5 - j;
  strs = strs.join("");
  while (j-- > 0) strs = " " + strs;
  console.log(strs)
}
```

[image]

Or even much, much better:

```
var spaces = "    ";
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  const strs = []
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    strs.push('* ')
  }
  console.log(spaces + strs.join(''))
  spaces = spaces.substring(0, spaces.length - 1);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote an algo,

```
int starBase = N;

for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    // print prefix spaces (formating)
    for(int k=0; k<(i-N);k++){
        print(" ");
    }

    // print *
    for(int j=0; j<i;j++){
        print("* ");
    }
    
    // new line
    print ("\n")
}
```

with N=5
your should work look like this.
its just a pseudo code you may have to convert it to your prefered langauge.

```
0
1     * 
2    * *
3   * * * 
4  * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
const strs = []
for(x=1;x <= 2-i; x++){
strs.push(' ')
}
for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
strs.push('*')
}
console.log(strs.join(''))
}
```

Comment: Also, code only answers are frowned upon in SO. Please add an explanation to improve the quality of your answer, and improve its long term value for future visitors. They should be able to learn from your post and apply the knowledge to their own issues. Finally, a prevalence of code-only answers tend to encourage "haz me the answer" free code writing questions, which are against the policy for the type Q SO is designed to handle. Quality answers are more likely to be upvoted.

Comment: Please explain why you think this solves the problem.